# WORDPRESS astra theme Different header menu for log in and log out user

Tags: php, wordpress

the question is just on the title, but well here's the problem i tried this code on my function.php which at first works fine, but suddenly i realized that the menus on footer changed to be the same as the header menus.

here is the code :

```
function wpc_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) { 
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
    } else { 
        $args['menu'] = 'Main Menu';
    } 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'wpc_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

What i want is to have a different header menus for user when they log in and log out, but the footer menus stays the same. i am currently learning how to add the conditional logic on the functions.php atm, but if there are other ways please let me know, thx in advance

Comment: How are the header and footer menu's added in the templates? Please post that code as well (most of us don't know the specifics of every theme out there).

Comment: hmm, i may not know what you are asking since this is my first porject with wordpress. but i am quite sure i didn't use any code for it, i use elementor page builder for the header and footer. and i simply make the menus in the menus tab from appereance tab. and put the menu i wanted in the elementor. (english is not my first language)

Comment: Your question is basically how you can customize a specific template/theme. Since we didn't build that theme, we can't really give you support on it either. If you don't know how Wordpress works yet, I suggest that you either do a bunch of research to learn it, or contact the theme developers and ask them for support.

Comment: Allright will do, but is there a way to only customize header within the functions.php file?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have a clue how they've built their theme.A theme can be built in many different ways, which is why we would need more info. But again, contact the theme developers if you have questions how to customize their theme that they have built.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for a reply but I just did this in the Astra theme today, so thought I would share the know-how for others who might need it. It can easily be adjusted for any WordPress theme actually:

You can check the location of the menu and only change the menu in the location(s) you decide (in this example 'primary' and 'mobile_menu' which is what Astra theme calls the the main nav locations for desktop and mobile) :

```
function custom_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) { 

  if( $args['theme_location'] == 'primary' || $args['theme_location'] == 'mobile_menu' ) {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
      $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
    }
  }
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'custom_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

If you dont want to use the explicit position of the menu (in my case the nav was in a widget in the footer and not a set theme location), you can also do the same thing by using the id, name or slug of the menu. For example if you want to change the menu 'test-menu' for 'test-menu-logged-out' if the user is logged out, you can use this:

```
function custom_2_wp_nav_menu_args ( $args = '' ) {
  $menu_slug = $args['menu']->slug;
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $menu_slug == 'test-menu' ){
    $args['menu'] = 'test-menu-logged-out';
  }
    return $args;  
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'custom_2_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```